# How to set tab based cookies in WebView2?

Tags: c++, cookies, webview2

How can I set a cookie which would be applicable for just a specific tab in the browser ? Chrome keeps cookies separated for normal mode and incognito mode. What i'm trying to achieve is similar to this but i want to do that for every tab in normal mode.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If I understand correctly, you have a tab based application with a `WebView2` on each tab and you want a separate environment for each `WebView2` so they have their own cookies.

There's an example of setting up an environment here: [Getting started with WebView2](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/microsoft-edge/webview2/gettingstarted/win32)
Go to **Step 3**.

**The second argument to `CreateCoreWebView2EnvironmentWithOptions` is the userdatafolder**. This must be **unique** to each tab.

You can for instance create a random folder name or add the tab index to the folder name.

Now the webview2 controls will have their own environment, including cache and **cookies**.